# Can I use HAProxy to convert outgoing requests?

Tags: haproxy

I would like to use HAProxy like this:

```
client              ->       server
(example:8080)      |        (example:80)               
                    |
                  HAProxy
                  Traffic going out from inside the server to `example:8080` change to `example:80`
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can, you can use `http-request set-header` to update the headers sent by the client, such as the "Host" header. You can also define the backend server to listen on any port that you want.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Can you explain in more detail? Or just show me some pseudo code.

Comment: I don't understand that HAProxy can intercept outgoing requests from specific applications or servers inside and change information about them.